# Browserstack.com ignoring X-UA-Compatible while testing for IE6-8?

Tags: x-ua-compatible, browser-testing, browserstack

While testing my site (www.luchtspin.nl) with the Utilu IE Collection (IE6-8 - http://utilu.com/IECollection) the results are fine. But as soon as I doublecheck my site via Browserstack.com, 'X-UA-Compatible' seems to be ignored.

Is this correct, does Browserstack ignore the X-UA-Compatible-setting? (Note: `X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge,chrome=1"` is correctly served through web.config.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more testing I found out that Browserstack ignores the `chrome=1` part of the X-UA-Compatible, so Chrome Frame is not activated. Makes sense of course. On the other hand in the browsers in the Utilu IE Collection in my VM, Chrome Frame *is* activated, hence my confusion.